# U+21B3 UTF8 character failure with \newunicodechar

Tags: unicode, newunicodechar

the following

```
% file testbismon.tex
%% see https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/ for more about Bismon
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,svgnames]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alltt}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342804/42406
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{charter}
%\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
% bigfoot enables \verb in footnotes
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\bmemail}[1]{{\href{mailto:#1}{\texttt{\textbf{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\bmurl}[1]{{\href{#1}{\texttt{\textbf{#1}}}}}


% see also http://www.sascha-frank.com/Arrow/latex-arrows.html and
% https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/newunicodechar/newunicodechar.pdf
% and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238135/42406
\newunicodechar{↳}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Lsh$}}

\begin{document}
\section{the test}
\begin{alltt}
the U+21B3 character is {\large ↳} \textit{DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH TIP RIGHTWARDS}
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

does not work on my Debian/Sid machine since `pdflatex testbismon.tex` gets the following error:

```
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-33.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uninames.dat)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-33.def)

! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 8627 = U+21B3,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-33.def.
(ucs)                Type H to see if it is available with options.

See the ucs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.50 the U+21B3 character is {\large ↳
                                        } \textit{DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH TIP R...

?
```

### Why does that error happens? How to get rid of it?

My above LaTeX code was inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238135/42406) answer. I am using:

```
 pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
 kpathsea version 6.3.1
```

and typing my LaTeX files using emacs 26.

Comment: `newunicodechar` *requires* not to use `utf8x`. Change the option to `utf8` (or remove the call to `inputenc` altogether). Also remove `\usepackage{ucs}`.

Answer (score 6):

You also get

```latex
Package newunicodechar Warning: This package only works if the document
(newunicodechar)                encoding is `utf8'.
```

Remove `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage{ucs}`.

Unrelated, but important: `hyperref` should be the last in your long list of packages. Also using `charter` and `stix` is a contradiction, remove the former. I wouldn't load `stmaryrd` along with `stix`. And `epsfig` is not to be used in newer documents: just use `graphicx` and its facilities.

[image]

Comment: Should I *replace* `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` by something else, or should it be entirely removed?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch With TeX Live 2018 or later, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is implied, so you don't need it.

Comment: "epsfig not to be used in newer documents" where "newer" means, anything written after 1994:-)

Comment: I will try that at work in a few hours, it should work, and then I'll accept the answer. A big thanks, I am struggling with such issues since two weeks

Comment: BTW, except from experience, how do you know that `charter` and `stix` are incompatible packages? Is there anywhere a web page saying that? I am still a bit of LaTeX newbie... (my greatest professional mistake in my life was to not writing my PhD, in 1990, using LaTeX. At that time a LaTeX distro filled the half of the disk of the Sun4/160 workstation I worked on)

Comment: This replaced all my math unicode with ligatures (e.g., σ became "fl").

Comment: @AlecJacobson Please, make a new question with details.