# general strategy to work around LaTeX packages inconsistencies

Tags: packages, texlive, debian

The motivating question is actually [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500959/42406).

I am still struggling to regenerate my [Bison draft report](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) from this [Bismon github](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) GPLv3+ software repository (using `make latexdoc`  on Linux/Debian/Sid or Buster; see its [README](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/README.md); that runs in about 3 seconds on a 4K€ Linux workstation, e.g. with AMD2970WX and 64 Gbytes RAM and SSD disk).

I am not, and don't have time or motivation, to become a LaTeXpert.

Is there any publicly available Web resources about LaTeX packages incompatibilities? I am not able to [STFW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/STFW) for one.

A combinatorial approach to add/remove one by one every used package is untractable: I am using about 33 LaTeX packages (with a trial and error approach) and 2<sup>33</sup> tests is not reasonable.

Taking into account [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500963/42406) excellent answer, my current `git diff`  w.r.t. [commit 54311004b61342cb311](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/commit/54311004b61342cb311d42b50a4c5e0c4ec23673) (I am wrongly using `git`  in some `svn` -like way, being the only `git` commiter) is just now

```
diff --git a/doc/bismon-chariot-doc.tex b/doc/bismon-chariot-doc.tex
index a81e131..51c815c 100644
--- a/doc/bismon-chariot-doc.tex
+++ b/doc/bismon-chariot-doc.tex
@@ -13,16 +13,16 @@
 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{fancybox}
-\usepackage{epsfig}
+%\usepackage{epsfig}
+\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{makeidx}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
-\usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{moreverb}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{boxedminipage}
 \usepackage[square]{natbib}
-\usepackage{charter}
+%\usepackage{charter}
 %\usepackage{inconsolata}
 \usepackage{hevea}
 \usepackage{listings}
@@ -31,13 +31,14 @@
 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \usepackage{catchfile}
 \usepackage{lastpage}
-\usepackage{stmaryrd}
+%\usepackage{stmaryrd}
 \usepackage{ucs}
 \usepackage{stix}
 \usepackage{newunicodechar}
 % bigfoot enables \verb in footnotes
 \usepackage{bigfoot}
 \usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
+\usepackage{hyperref}

 \newcommand{\bmemail}[1]{{\href{mailto:#1}{\texttt{\textbf{#1}}}}}
 \newcommand{\bmurl}[1]{{\href{#1}{\texttt{\textbf{#1}}}}}
@@ -45,6 +46,7 @@

 % see also http://www.sascha-frank.com/Arrow/latex-arrows.html
 % and https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/newunicodechar/newunicodechar.pdf
+%U+21B3 DOWNWARDS ARROW WITH TIP RIGHTWARDS
 \newunicodechar{↳}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\Lsh$}}
```

and it still does not work, since I am getting the same error

```
! Package ucs Error: Unknown Unicode character 8627 = U+21B3,
(ucs)                possibly declared in uni-33.def.
(ucs)                Type H to see if it is available with options.

See the ucs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

but I am still spending too much time to fix my mistakes (because I don't know well enough LaTeX). Of course I did try (without success) to comment the `\usepackage{ucs}` line.

NB. Problem solved (as a code monkey, so not understanding why and how) in git commit [32752acf09a](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/commit/32752acf09a45d417eacd20d76a23540bedac315). Thanks for the suggestion to look inside the generated `doc/bismon-chariot-doc.log` file. It has more information that stderr+stdout gives.

Comment: This isn't a package incompatibility, it's an issue in your input; however, I'd avoid the `ucs` package.

Comment: It [*is*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500963/42406) a package incompatibility: I am trying (as a LaTeX code monkey) randomly various combinations of them. But 2 to the power 24 to 33 is too much tests because `make latexdoc`  needs several seconds for a single run (on a 4000€ Linux desktop)

Comment: And as told in the question, I did try to avoid the `ucs`  package without success

Comment: And yes, some of the input is generated and contains weird UTF8 characters. For reasons explained in the document, I prefer to avoid changing them (but I eventually might, if that is *really* needed). BTW, the entire LaTeX code (except of course generated  `*.tex`  files) is available and the entire Bismon project (including hand-written `*.tex`  files and shell scripts generating `*.tex`  ones) is GPLv3+. On a Debian/Buster system you could reproduce the error (you'll just need to build `libonion` from its LGPLv3+ github code)

Comment: My [README.md](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/README.md) gives detailed building instructions in the best English I can write. But I am French, not natively English speaking

Comment: the error is not an incompatibility. You are using an input which needs additional code - standard latex does not provide definitions for the whole unicode. You need either an additional option for ucs, or (if you drop ucs) for inputenc, or you should use lualatex/xelatex (but this needs adjustments too). None of this can be done automatically without some latex skills.

Comment: I believe I am actually using lualatex

Comment: well if you use lualatex you shouldn't use ucs. But this is not something you should "believe": check the log-file.